# Spring Boot - Replicating the EntityManager created by Spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've been working on a Spring Boot project and i did all my database operations with the help of Spring Data JPA. So all i had was some entities and some repositories and all the CRUD operations worked fine.

But now, the project needed to talk to 2 databases. So what i did was i created all the new entities and repositories in a separate package. I noticed that now i need to have 2 EntityManagers, so i created 2 config files for both of the entity managers, configuring a `datasource`, an `entityManager` and a `transactionManager`. So now, instead of having 1 entityManager that spring boot gave me, i had 2 entityManagers that i created myself. And they worked fine, they both talked to the database they were supposed to talk to.

My problem is that i seem to have lost a lot of feature in my entityManager that spring-boot previously gave me. For example, my entity manager no longer created the schema based on its entities in my tests, which it previously did. Along with this, i am sure that i will run into other situations in which my `entityManager` will not be as properly configured as the one spring-boot would have given me.

So my idea was to only declare the second entity manager, and leave the config for the first one empty, however this did not work, and looking into `JpaBaseConfiguration` i noticed that spring will only create an entityManager if you do not already have one.

```java
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean({ LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class,
            EntityManagerFactory.class })
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
    //some code that will give you an entity manager
    );
```

And seeing as i MUST configure a second entityManager for the second database, it looks like im forced to create the first one as well, since spring-boot will skip creating one.

Which leads me to my question:

**Is there anyway that i can configure my first entity manager the same way that spring-boot would have done it for me? Or perhaps can i force spring to give me that entityManager even though i have another one declared for the second database? Is there any other way of solving my situation (i am thinking about just using a JDBCTemplate for the second database, however this is kinda of admiting defeat :'(   )?**

Sorry for the long question. Any answer is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) will help?

Comment: @crizzis Hi crizzis. Well not really, because this is pretty much my current setup. As you can see in the article, 2 entity managers are defined. My concern is that neither of those entity managers will be as well configured as spring-boot would have configured it for you.